# what is invalid about this syntax?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, syntax-error, simulation

I'm writing code to simulate x number of craps games and I have some code written that may or may not work. I'm not sure yet but I can't check because when I finish editing the module a syntax error notifies me that my code doesn't make sense. The thing is though I feel like I've used this syntax hundreds of times before. The error message reads

```
File "<ipython-input-5-9e8dfc269e5b>", line 7
if roll=7 or roll=11:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It doesn't like the equals sign? I don't understand why python can't read this. What is wrong?
here is all of the code for the simulation if it helps

```
def crap(x):
from random import randint
win=0
loss=0
for i in range(x):
    roll=rand(2,12)
    if roll = 7 or roll = 11:
        win=win+1
    elif roll = 2 or roll = 3 or roll = 12:
        loss=loss+1
    elif roll=4 or roll=5 or roll=6 or roll=8 or roll=9 or roll=10:
        rolln=randint(2,12)
        while rolln =! 7 or rolln =! roll:
            rolln=randint(2,12)
        if rolln = 7:
            loss=loss+1
        elif rolln = roll:
            win=win+1
```

Answer (score 3):

`=` is an assignement operator, you cannot use that in if-elif conditions. Use `==` for equality check.

```
if roll == 7 or roll == 11:
```

Secondly you can also reduce expressions like:

```
elif roll==4 or roll==5 or roll==6 or roll==8 or roll==9 or roll==10:
```

to:

```
elif roll in (4, 5, 6, 8, 9 ,10):
```

Comment: Thank you! The code looks so much better with that simplification!

Answer (score 2):

`=` is used to assign values to variables. Since you're trying to test for equality, you should be using `==`, e.g.

```
if roll == 7
```